# Why is the parameter from the URL coming back as undefined in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-urls

I am working on a project where I'm asking the user to enter a Company name in a form and before submitting the form I have button that redirects the user to the following URL and passes in the Company name that the user entered in the form:

```
http://.../sync/CompanyName
```

I'm trying to now call the `sync()` function and pass in the above Company name as a parameter.
This is the urls.py:

```
path('sync/<str:company>', views.sync, name='sync')
```

I am able to redirect it to the sync() view since I have some test lines in there that are being printed.
This is the views.py:

```
def sync(request,company):
    print(company)
    .
    .
    .
```

The issue is that the company name being printed above comes back as `undefined`. Am I missing something here?
How can I to do this without doing a POST request? I have also tried to get the company name using something like this: `print(request.GET.get(company))` when my URL was `http://.../sync/company=CompanyName` but that didn't work either - still came back as `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work just fine, but add a slash at the end of the url(as per [Django's design philosophies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#definitive-urls)):

```
path('sync/<str:company>/', views.sync, name='sync')
                        ^
```

Also, if you are getting `undefined`, then it is working fine. Because `undefined` is probably coming from your JavaScript code, not Python. If it were not working, then it would have thrown a error or you would have gotten `None` if you had passed `company=None` as keyword argument in the `sync` view function.

If you want to use `http://.../sync/?company=CompanyName`(ie using URL querystring), then you can use `request.GET` to get the company name. For example,

```
# url
path('sync/', views.sync, name='sync')

#view
def sync(request):
    print(request.GET.get('company', None))
```

FYI, GET methods should be idempotent, meaning it should not make any DB changes. So, consider using POST method if you intend to do changes in DB.

Comment: I think adding the '/' at the end of the URL did the trick! Thanks!!!